# Using packages in Vala

Tags: package, vala

I'm following an introductory tutorial about [vala](/questions/tagged/vala) and I want to make a simple application that simply shutdown the computer using the command `shutdown now`. I checked out this question [Executing system command in Vala](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3187469/executing-system-command-in-vala), and I found that I have to use a package named **posix**. I tried to add the following line in the `activate` method of my Application class:

```
Posix.system("shutdown now");
```

Then compile using:

```
valac --pkg gtk+-3.0 posix Application.vala
```

However, I got the following Error:

> error: posix not found
>
> Compilation failed: 1 error(s), 0 warning(s)

Sorry for this question but I'm new comer from scripting languages and I don't no how to quickly include libraries in Vala.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
valac --pkg gtk+-3.0 --pkg posix Application.vala
```

The `--pkg` argument needs a single package name after it, so you have to use as many `--pkg` arguments as you have packages.

Comment: Thank you. I'd like to mention that in `meson.build` **poisx** is not stated in dependencies using `dependency()` method but using get_compiler like: `meson.get_compiler('vala').find_library('posix')`